# How to retrieve last 5 records using LINQ method or query expression in C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

On my homepage, I want to show the recently added products. I have added a ChildAction to my controller but i am unable to understand what Linq query should i run to fetch the last five records.

Comment: the last 5 is the **first 5** if you order them the other way around ;o)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**LINQ**

```
var lastFiveProducts = (from p in products 
                        orderby p.ProductDate descending
                        select p).Take(5);
```

**Lambda**

```
var lastFiveProducts = products.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductDate).Take(5);
```

Which ever you prefer.

Comment: Which one is optimized more ? means not IEnumerable because it load all data and perform linq on it need IQueryable which takes specific records direct from database .?

Answer (score 42):

```
.Skip(count - 5);
```

or

```
.Reverse().Take(5).Reverse()
```

Comment: Best solution for me - I didn't have a field to order-by-descending on (as suggested in other answers)

Comment: Isn't `Take(5)` unnecessary?

Comment: @user, In the first case not strictly but its probably good habit if you have any concurrency going on.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest approach is to reverse your ordering (e.g. use `orderby foo descending`) and then use [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx). For example:

```
var recentProducts = products.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
                             .Take(5);
```

or in query expression form (which I wouldn't use for simple queries which are more easily expressed in the above form):

```
var recentProducts = (from product in products
                      orderby product.CreationDate descending
                      select product).Take(5);
```

Comment: hmm.....one other good thing came out of this....i didnt had a creationDate column in my table. Will add that too

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay Everyone (as you can see) assumed you had a date as you mentioned *recent products*. However, you could also do it via the product ID (given it's ordered in some way e.g. auto-increment) although I would recommend a created date of some sort.

Comment: @James , ya that what i really loved to learn. Adding a creation date will help in lot of things later on which i was missing. Thank you guys for the rescue. I asked for one and got two in return :)

Answer (score 9):

Install MoreLINQ Package, then:

```
CollectionName.TakeLast(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for selecting the last 5 with ascending

```
var query = from tbl in  (from tbl1 in object.Table orderby
tbl1.Column descending select tbl1).Take(5)  orderby tbl.Column
ascending  select tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
INT[]number = new int[] {3,6,8,2,3,7,0,2,5}

var result= (from r in number select r).reverse().take(5);
```

result: 
5
2
0
7
3